# I have a problem selecting a database column with hash in the name using spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to select a column with hash in the name. When I use select * from it returns data including the column with #. When I make a select using the column name I receive an error.

I'm using databricks accessing some .parquet files transformed in temp views. The cluster have 3 nodes and the Spark version is  Apache Spark 2.4.3, Scala 2.11 and I'm using Pyspark.

```
----Creation of temp views:

dictDbOwnTbls = dictionary with tables

    for tDb, args in dictDbOwnTbls.items():
        for owners in args.items():
            for tables in owners[1]:
                spark.read.format('parquet').options(header='true', 
    inferSchema='true').load('/.../raw/{}/{}/{}.parquet'.

    format(tDb, owners[0], tables)).createOrReplaceTempView(tables)
```

---- Error messages:-----------------------------------------------------

When I execute this code: select * from contratos, it works fine and return the column DS_OBSERVACAO##1 with other columns.

But when I execute: select DS_OBSERVACAO##1 from Contratos I received the following message:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------

```
 com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.
DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: 
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input '#' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 20)

== SQL ==
Select DS_OBSERVACAO##2  from Contratos
--------------------^^^

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:241)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:69)
at com.databricks.sql.parser.DatabricksSqlParser$$anonfun$parsePlan$1.apply(DatabricksSqlParser.scala:64)
at com.databricks.sql.parser.DatabricksSqlParser$$anonfun$parsePlan$1.apply(DatabricksSqlParser.scala:61)
at com.databricks.sql.parser.DatabricksSqlParser.parse(DatabricksSqlParser.scala:84)
at com.databricks.sql.parser.DatabricksSqlParser.parsePlan(DatabricksSqlParser.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:694)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:694)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:693)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:716)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLDriverLocal.scala:88)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLDriverLocal.scala:34)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:296)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.executeSql(SQLDriverLocal.scala:34)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.repl(SQLDriverLocal.scala:141)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$8.apply(DriverLocal.scala:368)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$8.apply(DriverLocal.scala:345)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:238)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:233)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:48)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:271)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:48)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:345)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:639)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:485)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:597)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:390)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.executeSql(SQLDriverLocal.scala:126)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.repl(SQLDriverLocal.scala:141)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$8.apply(DriverLocal.scala:368)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$8.apply(DriverLocal.scala:345)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:238)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:233)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:48)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:271)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:48)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:345)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:639)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:485)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:597)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:390)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: please share the query code that generates the error

Answer (score 0):

You have to use apostrophes:

```
select `DS_OBSERVACAO##1` from Contratos
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use it as below

```
spark.sql(s"""select `DS_OBSERVACAO##1` from contratos""")
```